# Heroku deployment not picking up latest commits when building Django app (e.g. recent changes to settings.py )

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

I'm using git trying to deploy to a staging pipeline on Heroku.

My build is failing. Based on the traceback (two of them, below), I have a general sense as to why. It involves my dynamic SECRET_KEY configuration variable in **settings.py**. The traceback refers to a python-decouple module installed previously. So I commented out the import line to that package in **settings.py**, removed the package from my requirements.txt, and used this instead:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
...
SECRET_KEY = str(os.getenv('SECRET_KEY'))
```

That's the latest version. When I save my changes, commit them, and then push to the staging pipeline, the traceback being returned refers to line 27 as if is still like this:

```
from decouple import config
...
SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')
```

I’m not sure why Heroku is not picking up the latest and most recent changes. Any ideas?

Here is my full build traceback:

```
$ git push staging main
Enumerating objects: 4016, done.
Counting objects: 100% (4016/4016), done.
Delta compression using up to 20 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3932/3932), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3965/3965), 6.41 MiB | 3.71 MiB/s, done.
Total 3965 (delta 302), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (302/302), completed with 15 local objects.
remote: Updated 7290 paths from c9c269d
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Using Python version specified in runtime.txt
remote: -----> Python version has changed from python-3.11.2 to python-3.10.10, clearing cache
remote: -----> Requirements file has been changed, clearing cached dependencies
remote: -----> Installing python-3.10.10
remote: -----> Installing pip 23.0.1, setuptools 63.4.3 and wheel 0.38.4
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting asgiref==3.6.0
remote:          Downloading asgiref-3.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
remote:        Collecting certifi==2022.12.7
remote:          Downloading certifi-2022.12.7-py3-none-any.whl (155 kB)
remote:        Collecting charset-normalizer==3.1.0
remote:          Downloading charset_normalizer-3.1.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (199 kB)
remote:        Collecting dj-database-url==1.3.0
remote:          Downloading dj_database_url-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (7.4 kB)
remote:        Collecting django==4.1.8
remote:          Downloading Django-4.1.8-py3-none-any.whl (8.1 MB)
remote:        Collecting django-ckeditor==6.5.1
remote:          Downloading django_ckeditor-6.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (2.4 MB)
remote:        Collecting django-heroku==0.3.1
remote:          Downloading django_heroku-0.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.2 kB)
remote:        Collecting django-jazzmin==2.6.0
remote:          Downloading django_jazzmin-2.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (2.8 MB)
remote:        Collecting django-js-asset==2.0.0
remote:          Downloading django_js_asset-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (4.9 kB)
remote:        Collecting gunicorn==20.1.0
remote:          Downloading gunicorn-20.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
remote:        Collecting heroku3==5.2.0
remote:          Downloading heroku3-5.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (161 kB)
remote:        Collecting idna==3.4
remote:          Downloading idna-3.4-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
remote:        Collecting pillow==9.5.0
remote:          Downloading Pillow-9.5.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl (3.4 MB)
remote:        Collecting psycopg2==2.9.6
remote:          Downloading psycopg2-2.9.6.tar.gz (383 kB)
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:        Collecting python-dateutil==2.8.2
remote:          Downloading python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB)
remote:        Collecting python-dotenv==1.0.0
remote:          Downloading python_dotenv-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
remote:        Collecting pytz==2023.3
remote:          Downloading pytz-2023.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (502 kB)
remote:        Collecting requests==2.28.2
remote:          Downloading requests-2.28.2-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
remote:        Collecting six==1.16.0
remote:          Downloading six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
remote:        Collecting sqlparse==0.4.3
remote:          Downloading sqlparse-0.4.3-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
remote:        Collecting typing-extensions==4.5.0
remote:          Downloading typing_extensions-4.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (27 kB)
remote:        Collecting urllib3==1.26.15
remote:          Downloading urllib3-1.26.15-py2.py3-none-any.whl (140 kB)
remote:        Collecting whitenoise==6.4.0
remote:          Downloading whitenoise-6.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
remote:        Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2
remote:          Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py): started
remote:          Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:          Created wheel for psycopg2: filename=psycopg2-2.9.6-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl size=159971 sha256=633a65b5bc08894912275e69ae23e45eb18511e0fb0be56037f9da7f9d301ceb
remote:          Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-pghrau7m/wheels/a2/65/83/78e6f42d3b8e22115e894576b71799d96ab5a790b8f7bcfa85
remote:        Successfully built psycopg2
remote:        Installing collected packages: pytz, whitenoise, urllib3, typing-extensions, sqlparse, six, python-dotenv, psycopg2, pillow, idna, gunicorn, charset-normalizer, certifi, asgiref, requests, python-dateutil, django, heroku3, django-js-asset, django-jazzmin, dj-database-url, django-heroku, django-ckeditor
remote:        Successfully installed asgiref-3.6.0 certifi-2022.12.7 charset-normalizer-3.1.0 dj-database-url-1.3.0 django-4.1.8 django-ckeditor-6.5.1 django-heroku-0.3.1 django-jazzmin-2.6.0 django-js-asset-2.0.0 gunicorn-20.1.0 heroku3-5.2.0 idna-3.4 pillow-9.5.0 psycopg2-2.9.6 python-dateutil-2.8.2 python-dotenv-1.0.0 pytz-2023.3 requests-2.28.2 six-1.16.0 sqlparse-0.4.3 typing-extensions-4.5.0 urllib3-1.26.15 whitenoise-6.4.0
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/popup_response.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
remote:        Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/cancel.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
remote:        Post-processing 'vendor/bootswatch/default/bootstrap.min.css' failed!
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "/tmp/build_6ab523f7/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
remote:            main()
remote:          File "/tmp/build_6ab523f7/manage.py", line 18, in main
remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
remote:            utility.execute()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
remote:            self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
remote:            self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 448, in execute
remote:            output = self.handle(*args, **options)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 209, in handle
remote:            collected = self.collect()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 154, in collect
remote:            raise processed
remote:        whitenoise.storage.MissingFileError: The file 'vendor/bootswatch/default/bootstrap.min.css.map' could not be found with <whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage object at 0x7f0bf2f350c0>.
remote:        The CSS file 'vendor/bootswatch/default/bootstrap.min.css' references a file which could not be found:
remote:          vendor/bootswatch/default/bootstrap.min.css.map
remote:        Please check the URL references in this CSS file, particularly any
remote:        relative paths which might be pointing to the wrong location.
remote: 
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
remote: 
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
remote: 
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
remote: 
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to <project-name>
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/<project-name>.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/<project-name>.git'
```

As you can see, it says: “Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote: See traceback above for details.” So here is **$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput** on my remote server which does provide further insight:

```
› heroku ps:exec -a <project-name>
 ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.67.2 to 7.68.2.
Establishing credentials... done
Connecting to web.1 on ⬢ <project-name>.. 
(failed reverse-i-search)`': ^C
~ $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/app/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 386, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 190, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/<project-name>/settings.py", line 27, in <module>
    SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/decouple.py", line 248, in __call__
    return self.config(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/decouple.py", line 107, in __call__
    return self.get(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/decouple.py", line 92, in get
    raise UndefinedValueError('{} not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.'.format(option))
decouple.UndefinedValueError: SECRET_KEY not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.
```

As you can see it is referring to line 27 with a SECRET_KEY using decouple’s config function but I have assuredly commented that out in my latest settings.py as described originally above. So I am not sure why Heroku is not looking at the most recent version in my latest commit.

Any idea what could be going on?

Please note: I added **git** as a tag because that is the tool I am using to handle my Heroku deploys.

For what it may be worth, if it helps, here is my full settings.py that I am working with:

```
"""
Django settings for <project-name>.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.1.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os
import django_heroku
# from decouple import config
import dj_database_url
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
# SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')
SECRET_KEY = str(os.getenv('SECRET_KEY'))

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*',]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'jazzmin',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'ckeditor',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'contributors',
    'articles',
    # 'landings.apps.LandingsConfig',
    'stock_pages',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = '<project-name>.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = '<project-name>.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases
'''
DATABASES = {
   'default': dj_database_url.config(
       default='sqlite:///'+os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
       conn_max_age=600)
   }
# DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(default='')
db_from_env=dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)\
''' 
DATABASES = { 'default' : 
                {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql'}
             }
DATABASES = {
   'default': dj_database_url.config(
       default='sqlite:///'+os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
       conn_max_age=600)
   }
# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static']
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"
CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = "/staticfiles/ckeditor/ckeditor/"

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

django_heroku.settings(locals())

JAZZMIN_SETTINGS = {
    "order_with_respect_to": ["stock_pages", "contributors", "articles",],
}
```

Comment: The push _failed_. There are no new commits for Heroku to "pick up".

Answer (score 1):

Heroku is rejecting your push because its pre-receive hook fails. The `SECRET_KEY` error is indirectly related: you've commented it out in your latest version, but since Heroku's pre-receive hook fails Heroku is refusing the latest version. (Pre-receive hooks are a gate for receiving pushes: if the hook fails, then the session ends and the push doesn't land.)

The trace suggests that this may be your issue:

```
remote:        whitenoise.storage.MissingFileError: The file 'vendor/bootswatch/default/bootstrap.min.css.map' could not be found with <whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage object at 0x7f0bf2f350c0>.
remote:        The CSS file 'vendor/bootswatch/default/bootstrap.min.css' references a file which could not be found:
remote:          vendor/bootswatch/default/bootstrap.min.css.map
remote:        Please check the URL references in this CSS file, particularly any
remote:        relative paths which might be pointing to the wrong location.
```

I'd start by looking into that, since it's blocking your pushes.

Comment: Thank you Jim. This is insight. I will redirect my attention to this part of the traceback, take a detailed look into this, and report back here with what I find.